# Google Wallet Console - Class ID

Tags: android, kotlin, google-pay, wallet

I am trying to integrate google wallet loyalty cards into my application.
I succesfully tested using the ids from the demo project .
Now I want to prepare for production. I received access for google wallet but I do not know how to complete "class id" . Did not find in any documentation .
Thanks all for your time

[image]

Comment: could you figure this out already? I am also stuck on this step. I gave the class id a normal String "member", but I am not sure if this is how it is supposed to work. I cannot add a new object when using <issuerid>.member as `classId` in the genericObject.

Answer (score 0):

You may enter whatever id you want (I didn't find the field restrictions)
and then you use it to set the classId with your issuerId, like this:

```
objectPayload.classId = `${issuerId}.${classId}`
```